# Validation Rule Opty Stage

Tags: apex, opportunity, validation-rule

Validation rule need to be triggered when Opty Stage is 'Closed Won', but the below rule is triggered when stage is new

```
AND(
OR(
ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Closed Won")),
ISBLANK( Contact_Name__c ),
ISBLANK( Closed_Won_date__c )
)
```

edit:

The fields are marked required.

Hence, got the error message regardless of the value of the stage

Comment: This formula is missing a closing parenthesis. Is this formula complete otherwise?

Comment: @DavidReed it has closing parenthesis, the OR condition is closed after the Closed Won

Comment: So it is. I misread; apologies.

Comment: @DavidReed, rule is working. Actually the two fields are required so due to that the error message of the rule was not displayed on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses were out of place, so it only triggered when both fields were blank. You probably meant to use OR for the missing fields:

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
  OR(
    ISBLANK( Contact_Name__c ),
    ISBLANK( Closed_Won_date__c )
  )
)
```

Note, however, that this is a bad user experience (UX). Each validation rule should trigger for only one field, so the error can highlight the field:

## Rule 1

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
  ISBLANK( Contact_Name__c )
)
```

## Rule 2

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
  ISBLANK( Closed_Won_date__c )
)
```

Comment: Thank You for the best practises. actually the fields used for the rule are marked as required so I overlooked it. Tested the rule by removing the required checkbox. Now I'm good. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The fields are marked required.

Hence, got the error message regardless of the value of the stage